# Is there a tool that will format MySQL output?

Tags: mysql

MySQL's command line output is very unreadable.  I know about \G, but sometimes it's not me running the query.  For example, if somebody emails or IMs me query output, or if PHPUnit is auto printing output.

Is there some light weight online tool already made that I can drop in a MySQL command line output and it display it in a readable format?

Comment: I can write you one...  You can write one too...

Comment: I thought of that, and just pasted an output string into eclipse.  Eclipse formatted it.  It would still be nice though, if there was a tool where I could IM somebody a link rather than MySQL's output.  Again, this is if the output was generated outside of my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting the output into eclipse is what I've been doing.  If anybody ever leaves a good tool, I'll accept their answer instead.

Comment: Much later, realized copying into notepad works like a charm too..

Answer (score 3):

Except from forcing them to use [the --table option](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysql/) when using mysql, I don't know :)

I'm going to have a look if such a tool exists.